# jQuery replay button at video's end?

Tags: jquery

I have a Wistia video as a background and using custom play button. Instead of looping it, I'd like the users to be able to replay it at will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Wistia dashboard, on video customize screen, you can set the option for looping video or stop video on last frame. You can set the option of video behaviour as 'Pause on the last frame'

Comment: I know the option, but how is this going to add a replay button? Keep in mind I've hidden all control buttons, since my video is played by a custom button. I'd also like my replay one to be custom as well.

Comment: You must have written code to hide the play button when video start playing. You can use wistia js api method 'end' which is fired when video is ended. On end method, just display custom play button

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do the end method in JS?

Comment: wistiaEmbed = jQuery("#my_iframe")[0].wistiaApi;
wistiaEmbed.bind("end", function() {
// Write code display button
});